# Computing convolution on non-uniform sample

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

How to efficiently convolve the function $h(t)=H(t)e^{-t}$ with a function $x(t)$ sampled non-uniformly, i.e. $\{x(t_0), x(t_1), ..., x(t_{N-1})\}$?
$H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, and the Fourier transform of $h(t)$ is $\tilde{h}(\omega)=(1-i\omega)^{-1}$.

**What I have done**

If $x(t)$ is sampled uniformly, I can apply the Fourier transform to $x(t)$ (with enough 0-paddings) to get $\tilde{x}(\omega)$, multiply it with $\tilde{h}(\omega)$, and apply inverse Fourier transform to get the convolution result.
If $x(t)$ is sampled non-uniformly, the first thing that comes to my mind is to apply the non-uniform discrete Fourier transform (NUDFT).
However, it is unclear to me which NUDFT I should use (type I, II, or III?), which points in the frequency domain I should choose, and how to invert them back?

Answer (score 2):

After briefly reading the [user manual](https://cims.nyu.edu/cmcl/nufft/nufft_manual.pdf) of NUFFT you simply have to choose both variants I and II as forward and backward transformation.
With this you can proceed in a similar way as having uniformal distributed data since the modal representation  is still based on integer frequencies.

As alternative you may use [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution).

**Edit**:

We can define the **discrete Fourier transform** via trigonometric Interpolation

\begin{align}
f_{h}(x)&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k e^{ik x} 
 =\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k \phi_{k}(x),
\label{al:approx}\\
        &=c_{0}\phi_{0}(x)\;+\; c_{1} \phi_{1}(x) \;+ \; \ldots \;+ \; c_{N-1} \phi_{N-1}(x),
\end{align}

by minimizing the error at $N$ specific collocation points

\begin{align}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
        \phi_{0}(x_{0})   &  \phi_{1}(x_{0})   & \cdots & \phi_{N-1}(x_{0})  \\
        \phi_{0}(x_{1})   &  \phi_{1}(x_{1})   & \cdots & \phi_{N-1}(x_{1})  \\
        \vdots            &  \vdots            & \ddots & \vdots             \\
        \phi_{0}(x_{N-1}) &  \phi_{1}(x_{N-1}) & \cdots & \phi_{N-1}(x_{N-1})
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{\underline{V}}}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
c_{0}  \\
c_{1}   \\
\vdots  \\
c_{N-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{c}}
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
f_{0}  \\
f_{1}  \\
\vdots \\
f_{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{f}}.
\end{align}

Here $\mathbf{\underline{V}}$ is the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
(see also [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)), $\mathbf{c}$ are the **modal** and $\mathbf{f}$ the **nodal** values.

You may define the **forward and backward DFT** as

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}: \ \mathbf{c}&= \mathbf{\underline{V}}^{-1}  \mathbf{f}, \\ \mathcal{F}^{-1}: \mathbf{f}&= \mathbf{\underline{V}}  \> \mathbf{c}.
\end{align}

Note that the inverse of a matrix is generally defined as

\begin{align}
\mathbf{\underline{V}}^{-1} = \text{det}(\mathbf{\underline{V}})^{-1} \text{adj}(\mathbf{\underline{V}}).
\end{align}

where $\text{det}(\mathbf{\underline{V}})^{-1}$ is a scaling factor and has to be taken into account.

Comment: NUFFT type II is the adjoint, but not the inverse of type I NUFFT. This page (https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/PIRODDI1/NUFT/node7.html) also shows that type I then type II NUFFT does not reconstruct the original signal. If we take type I & II as the forward & backward transformation, then it will produce incorrect results for the convolution.

Comment: @Firman Sure, that's why I pointed to the manual since the scaling factor (determinant) is merely a convention and differs in some treatments.